# Whether nodejs support runtime dependency?

Tags: node.js

I have created a nodejs application. It has `jdbc` dependency in my package.json file. I found that my app can't be launched if the target machine doesn't have `jre` installed. Since `jdbc` is only an optional function in my app, I wonder whether there is a way for me to allow the app running in an environment which doesn't have `jre` installed.

Ideally, I want to implement a logic like this:

1, detect whether the target machine installs `jre` or not

2, If installed, enable this feature

3, if not, disable this feature

So I need a runtime dependency on nodejs in order to support this requirement.

Comment: `require` is just regular JavaScript code, so you can `try { ... } catch(err) { ... }` around it.

Comment: @tadman this doesn't really get around the core issue- which is that it should activate iff Java is installed.

Comment: A lot of time it's better to have some kind of settings system than to automagically detect and use it just because it's installed. What if as a user I don't want Java involved in your app, I just have it installed for other reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has two parts:

1. **Can you detect whether the machine has Java installed?** 
   Yes- you can use code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734477/verify-if-java-is-installed-from-node-js) which would execute a shell command to determine if the JRE is installed, and possibly verify the version.
2. **Can you selectively include a dependency at runtime?** 
   Also yes- you can just use an `if` statement like:

   `var jbdc;
   if(java_installed){
     jbdc = require('jbdc');
   }`

This being said, if you are getting an error at install time from `jbdc` you are still going to have to manually choose to install `jbdc` if Java is supported.  To do this, add `jbdc` to your `package.json` as an [optional dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json).