# Does AWS lambda for Node provide JVM environment?

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am interested in using AWS lambda for Node to talk to a Hive cluster.
I plan on using https://github.com/CraZySacX/node-jdbc which requires JVM environment.

Using [Verify if Java is installed from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734477/verify-if-java-is-installed-from-node-js) I was able to print some info about whether or not if Java is installed on Lambda.

```
START RequestId: 767a7997-2876-11e8-b7a5-43dd5c602cd0 Version: $LATEST
2018-03-15T17:29:50.131Z    767a7997-2876-11e8-b7a5-43dd5c602cd0    [ 'openjdk version "1.8.0_141"',
  'OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b16)',
  'OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b16, mixed mode)',
  '' ]
2018-03-15T17:29:50.134Z    767a7997-2876-11e8-b7a5-43dd5c602cd0    nojava
END RequestId: 767a7997-2876-11e8-b7a5-43dd5c602cd0
REPORT RequestId: 767a7997-2876-11e8-b7a5-43dd5c602cd0  Duration: 118.05 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms     Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 43 MB
```

This looks promising, but I am concerned about the line that reads `nojava`. I am not sure that that means.

So basically, my question boils down to, Does AWS lambda for Node provide JVM environment?

Comment: Why not just use a Java lambda function?

Comment: You cannot rely on it, it may change in time. Using NodeJS lambdas AWS guarantees the Node runtime will work. Indeed using Java based lambda (or calling it from your NodeJS lambda) would be more appropriate option