# Angular javascript to detect and install jdk

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, electron

I am creating an application where I need java **jdk** to be installed.

So I want to create a detection function for jdk in system and if not found then install it by the setup which i will provide  and also store it **Environment Variables -> System variable**s as `JAVA_HOME` `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.y.z`  by default.

I searched through lot but not getting exact idea how will I achieve this.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. Are you wanting to use JavaScript and Angular to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason about tagging javascript and angularjs here? This seems to be java-related, rather than javascript-related.

Comment: @PeterMellett yes, that's correct . I need Angular javascript/javascript function to achieve this.

Comment: @briosheje This is angular app. I want to do the task using javascript function.

Comment: Do you mind expanding your question a little? How are you running your angular app?

Comment: @PeterMellett I am creating desktop application using Electron and AngularJS. I am running it by node/ electron command.

Comment: @WhoAmI Ok, tagging electron is indeed very important at this point.

Comment: You can check this for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734477/verify-if-java-is-installed-from-node-js which will help you check whether java is installed or not. You can run any node script from electron's main process, then talk with the renderer through the IPC channel so that you are aware about whether java is installed or not.

Comment: @briosheje ok let me try.

Comment: @briosheje This gives me JRE version . I need to check JDK is installed in the system or not.

Comment: @WhoAmI with electron, from the **main** process, you can spawn a shell, and execute `javac -version`. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js . The base concept is that you can run a shell command, so you can easily check whether the JDK is installed or not directly from there.

Comment: @briosheje Ok I got it. Thanks

Comment: (BEWARE of security issues though, avoid injecting dynamic parameters in the shell command, otherwise be careful).

Comment: @briosheje when I am trying to run `.spawn('javac', ['-version']);` according to this, gives me no output.

Answer (score 0):

I need to know more about your app, which  Angular or Nodejs as the backend of your app and if angular then you need to use ironic or some similar hybrid technology for accessing system level permission like installing software and updating Environment Variables. If you are using NODEJS as backend then you can use [exec](https://nodejs.org/docs/v8.1.4/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)  to execute system command and also you can install your JDK with silent installation [refer the link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#jdk-silent-installation)

Comment: Ok . I am using Node.JS as backend. I have an idea of `child_process` . silent installation will only install silently. I need to set the path also in Environment variables automatically. First search jdk ,if found then skip, not found install silently and put it in Environment Variable.

Comment: The MSDN documentation for environment variables tells you what to do:

To programmatically add or modify system environment variables, add them to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment registry key, then broadcast a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message with lParam set to the string "Environment". This allows applications, such as the shell, to pick up your updates.

You will of course need admin rights to do this. I know of no way to broadcast a windows message from Windows batch so you'll need to write a small program to do this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/ProcThread/environment-variables please read the link