# Installing Java on user's system from Node app

Tags: java, node.js, electron

I'm creating a node (electron) app in which the users use visual programming which creates Java source code. The user then has the source code on their machine, and that project can be run from inside the node app by using child process.

The issue is when the user doesn't have Java installed on their machine. I understand that I can check if Java is installed [using the method shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734477/verify-if-java-is-installed-from-node-js). The issue is how can I download/install the JDK on the users machine from inside my node application?

Comment: I would add a JDK (probably zipped) to the electron app (as asset) and write to a temporary location on local disk. En general, a JDK does not need any special installation. Or download the ZIP in the electron app from e.g. https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk17/ri/openjdk-17+35_windows-x64_bin.zip and unzip to local disk.

Comment: @PeterMmm I was worried about licensing for distributing the JDK, so I guess downloading it would be a workaround.

Comment: hey @John i am doing the exact same, my app requires JRE to be installed in the client system for it to make some functionalities work. did you figure out a way to do it?